# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when trying to make discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot, however whenever I run the `-setcaps` command I get :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

I'm not exactly sure what is causing this. I would appreciate whatever help you can provide. Not exactly sure what to add to this to provide more details, I'm using the latest stable version of node.js and editing with notpad++

[image: The Error]

```
// Call Packages
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const economy = require('discord-eco');

// Define client for Discord
const client = new Discord.Client();
// We have to define a moderator role, the name of a role you need to run certain commands
const modRole = 'Sentinel';

// This will run when a message is recieved...
client.on('message', message => {

    // Variables
    let prefix = '-';
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    // Lets also add some new variables
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "); // This slices off the prefix, then stores everything after that in an array split by spaces.
    let args = cont.slice(1); // This removes the command part of the message, only leaving the words after it seperated by spaces

    // Commands

    // Ping - Let's create a quick command to make sure everything is working!
    if (message.content.toUpperCase() === `${prefix}PING`) {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }

    // Add / Remove Money For Admins
    if (msg.startsWith(`${prefix}SETCAPS`)) {

        // Check if they have the modRole
        if (!message.member.roles.find("name", modRole)) { // Run if they dont have role...
            message.channel.send('**You need the role `' + modRole + '` to use this command...**');
            return;
        }

        // Check if they defined an amount
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.send(`**You need to define an amount. Usage: ${prefix}SETCAPS <amount> <user>**`);
            return;
        }

        // We should also make sure that args[0] is a number
        if (isNaN(args[0])) {
            message.channel.send(`**The amount has to be a number. Usage: ${prefix}SETCAPS <amount> <user>**`);
            return; // Remember to return if you are sending an error message! So the rest of the code doesn't run.
        }

        // Check if they defined a user
        let defineduser = '';
        if (!args[1]) { // If they didn't define anyone, set it to their own.
            defineduser = message.author.id;
        } else { // Run this if they did define someone...
            let firstMentioned = message.mentions.users.first();
            defineduser = firstMentioned.id;
        }

        // Finally, run this.. REMEMBER IF you are doing the guild-unique method, make sure you add the guild ID to the end,
        economy.updateBalance(defineduser + message.guild.id, parseInt(args[0])).then((i) => { // AND MAKE SURE YOU ALWAYS PARSE THE NUMBER YOU ARE ADDING AS AN INTEGER
            message.channel.send(`**User defined had ${args[0]} added/subtraction from their account.**`)
        });

    }

    // Balance & Money
    if (msg === `${prefix}BALANCE` || msg === `${prefix}MONEY`) { // This will run if the message is either ~BALANCE or ~MONEY

        // Additional Tip: If you want to make the values guild-unique, simply add + message.guild.id whenever you request.
        economy.fetchBalance(message.author.id + message.guild.id).then((i) => { // economy.fetchBalance grabs the userID, finds it, and puts the data with it into i.
            // Lets use an embed for This
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(`**${message.guild.name} Stash**`)
                .setColor(0xff9900) // You can set any HEX color if you put 0x before it.
                .addField('Stash Owner',message.author.username,true) // The TRUE makes the embed inline. Account Holder is the title, and message.author is the value
                .addField('Stash Contents',i.money,true)


            // Now we need to send the message
            message.channel.send({embed})

        })

    }

});

client.login('TOKEN HIDDEN');
```

Comment: Could you send us the whole error please where we see which code line is causing this error

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was causing your error but let's give it a try. I edited the check if the user mentioned someone.

```
// Call Packages
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const economy = require('discord-eco');

// Define client for Discord
const client = new Discord.Client();
// We have to define a moderator role, the name of a role you need to run certain commands
const modRole = 'Sentinel';

// This will run when a message is recieved...
client.on('message', message => {

    // Variables
    let prefix = '-';
    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    // Lets also add some new variables
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "); // This slices off the prefix, then stores everything after that in an array split by spaces.
    let args = cont.slice(1); // This removes the command part of the message, only leaving the words after it seperated by spaces

    // Commands

    // Ping - Let's create a quick command to make sure everything is working!
    if (message.content.toUpperCase() === `${prefix}PING`) {
        message.channel.send('Pong!');
    }

    // Add / Remove Money For Admins
    if (msg.startsWith(`${prefix}SETCAPS`)) {

        // Check if they have the modRole
        if (!message.member.roles.find("name", modRole)) { // Run if they dont have role...
            message.channel.send('**You need the role `' + modRole.name + '` to use this command...**');
            return;
        }

        // Check if they defined an amount
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.send(`**You need to define an amount. Usage: ${prefix}SETCAPS <amount> <user>**`);
            return;
        }

        // We should also make sure that args[0] is a number
        if (isNaN(args[0])) {
            message.channel.send(`**The amount has to be a number. Usage: ${prefix}SETCAPS <amount> <user>**`);
            return; // Remember to return if you are sending an error message! So the rest of the code doesn't run.
        }

        // Check if they defined a user
        let defineduser = '';
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
        defineduser = user.id

        // Finally, run this.. REMEMBER IF you are doing the guild-unique method, make sure you add the guild ID to the end,
        economy.updateBalance(defineduser + message.guild.id, parseInt(args[0])).then((i) => { // AND MAKE SURE YOU ALWAYS PARSE THE NUMBER YOU ARE ADDING AS AN INTEGER
            message.channel.send(`**User defined had ${args[0]} added/subtraction from their account.**`)
        });

    }

    // Balance & Money
    if (msg === `${prefix}BALANCE` || msg === `${prefix}MONEY`) { // This will run if the message is either ~BALANCE or ~MONEY

        // Additional Tip: If you want to make the values guild-unique, simply add + message.guild.id whenever you request.
        economy.fetchBalance(message.author.id + message.guild.id).then((i) => { // economy.fetchBalance grabs the userID, finds it, and puts the data with it into i.
            // Lets use an embed for This
            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription(`**${message.guild.name} Stash**`)
                .setColor(0xff9900) // You can set any HEX color if you put 0x before it.
                .addField('Stash Owner', message.author.username, true) // The TRUE makes the embed inline. Account Holder is the title, and message.author is the value
                .addField('Stash Contents', i.money, true)


            // Now we need to send the message
            message.channel.send({
                embed
            })

        })

    }

});

client.login('TOKEN HIDDEN')
```

Comment: Hasn't fixed it sadly, Thanks for trying :(